# In Oracle SQL, how do I only add text to a column only if it is not null?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column in my query like this :

```
ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5)|| ' days' AS "Average SOD Approval duration"
```

The problem is that , when my data is null, I get 'days' printed in each null box. I want there to be nothing in the output , if it's null. and only append "days" when there *is* data.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest `NVL2` instead of `case`

```
SELECT nvl2(ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5),
            ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) || 'days',
            NULL) AS "Average SOD Approval duration"
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is shorter way:

```
select ltrim(round(d1-d2, 5)|| ' days', ' days') dt from test
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad6ea1/1)

---

Edit: If at least one of dates is null, date difference is also null. After concatenation of " days" you get only this string as value, so trimming phrase " days" from left side gives null. If dates are not null trimming from left has no impact. Documentation of function [ltrim()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions083.htm). In this case with trimming you can shorten syntax and avoid repeated calculations.

Comment: Yeh this one i would say is the best answer

Comment: My only concern with this answer is whether it's as easy to understand what it's doing. Sometimes it's better to go with a more verbose answer if it aids future maintenance.

Comment: @Boneist - this query is so self-explanatory that I did not any comments at first, but generally you are right, so I added explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's not the world's most complicated expression, but it's something you'd have to think about first before realising that it's just adding " days" to non-null values, whereas the case/nvl2 implementations make it pretty obvious what - and why - you're doing it. NB. I'm not saying that it's something that the OP shouldn't use, I'm just adding a note of caution into the wind *{:-)

Comment: I need some more coffee to actually understand it :P .. a puzzle of sorts, thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) IS NULL 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5)|| ' days'
            END AS "Average SOD Approval duration"
FROM yourtablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement:

```
CASE WHEN ROUND((xyz.date - abc.date), 5) IS NOT NULL 
          THEN ROUND((xyz.date    - abc.date), 5)||' days'
END
```

You could add in an "ELSE NULL" clause to make it doubly clear that if the conditions aren't met then null would be returned if you wanted to make the case statement especially explicit, but since that's the default, it's not necessary.